# Замена атрибута boder в frameset

Tags: css3, xhtml, css

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, чем можно заменить атрибут border в frameset в css, чтоб не было границ между фреймами.

Просто, когда я вставляю этот атрибут в frameset, в валидаторе появляется ошибка.

Вот код, чтоб понятней было

```
<frameset cols="40%,*" border="0">
    <frame src="frame1.html" name="left" />
    <frame src="frame2.html" name="right" />
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще сама конструкция фреймов вместо `<body>` физически и морально устарела и **через css фреймсеты/фреймы контролировать нельзя**!
Почитайте [про аттрибуты `<frameset>/<frame>`](http://my60.ru/koders/f.php?p=html&f=frameset&SID=fdt22cotucfn6f6a8bue8ro0v6)
Настоятельно рекомендую вместо <frameset> использовать `<iframe>` он современный (по сравнению с frameset) его можно (и нужно) вставлять в `<body>` как любой другой тег (`<div> <span>` и т.д) он контролируется (не полностью но всё же) через `css` и имеет те же св-ва что `<frame>`.
***UPD:*** А ещё `<iframe>` используют для `AJAX` в браузерах не поддерживающих его на уровне `JavaScript` так что умение пользоваться `<iframe>` ваш шаг на пути к `AJAX` :)

Comment: с тем что он устаревает я согласен, но мало ли, вдруг приспичит воспользоваться

Answer (score 0):

Какой DOCTYPE используете? При правильном DOCTYPE валидатор ругаться бы не стал.

Либо вы используете строгий DOCTYPE где не допускается не только border="0" у frameset, но и само использование frameset, либо вы используете подходящий DOCTYPE в котором эта конструкция не вызовет нареканий.
Если нужен именно frameset попробуйте:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
```

css не работает с framese. Как правильно заметил [[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules) это древний tag и он имеет статус deprecated во всех последних DOCTYPE.